# Why is my code wrong incomparsion to my calculator and online calculators can someone let me know whats wrong with it

Tags: python

```
 from math import cos
 from math import  sin
 from math import pi
 a0 = int(input("a0:"))
 b0 = int(input("b0:"))
 N = int(input("N:"))
 L = int(input("L:"))
 X = int(input("X:"))
 n = 0
 an = a0
 bn = b0
 y=0
 for i in range(N):
    n = n+1
    an = an + 10   
    bn = bn * 10   
    y = an * (cos(((n*pi*X)/(L))))+ (bn*(sin((n*pi*X)/(L))))
 total = a0 + y
 print(total)
```

Im assuming that the y = .... code is wrong since the an and bn code works fine lmk[Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLx7N.png)

Comment: You should provide a minimum reproducible example that includes expected vs actual output.

Comment: Are you sure that all those input variables should be ints and not floats?  Obviously N will be an integer, but the formula looks like it's intended for all the others to be floats.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a *sum* you need to be keeping track of that inside the loop. Right now `y` will just be the result of that last iteration.

```
 from math import cos
 from math import  sin
 from math import pi
 a0 = int(input("a0:"))
 b0 = int(input("b0:"))
 N = int(input("N:"))
 L = int(input("L:"))
 X = int(input("X:"))
 n = 0
 an = a0
 bn = b0
 y=0
 for i in range(N):
    n = n+1
    an = an + 10   
    bn = bn * 10   
    y += an * (cos(((n*pi*X)/(L))))+ (bn*(sin((n*pi*X)/(L))))
 total = a0 + y
 print(total)
```